# How can I write ajax POST requests for repetitive items on a page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, post

I've previously written AJAX requests for unique, singular items on a page (such as casting a vote for an image, of which there can only be one vote, and only one image at a time, and the `image_id` has been previously fetched from the db).

But how can I create secure ajax posts for objects which are not unique, such as comments on a page:

```
<span>Comment 1</span>
<span>Comment 2</span>
```

Each page can have multiple comments, and you can vote for each comment, for example. When the user clicks the 'vote' button, how can I tell AJAX & PHP what vote button for what comment was clicked?

An example of this would be stackoverflow's voting system. How does it know which comment you voted for?

Comment: You mean using checkboxes or radios? Why don't you create the HTML markup for the form you're trying to submit via AJAX and we can help you on this end. You should definitely investigate the `.serialize()` method in jQuery which can hook up all of your form elements into a single submittable stream of data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to take your example of StackOverflow's comment system; here is some sample markup from a comment:

```
<tr id="comment-27519352" class="comment" data-commentid="27519352">
    <td></td>
    <td class="comment-text"><div><span class="comment-copy">
        ...
    </div></form></td>
</tr>
```

Note that the comment has a data attribute of `data-commentid`. This will be passed to the server as part of the AJAX request (probably as part of a JSON object) so the server-side code knows what comment to assign the upvote to. Similarly, the link to upvote the comment is within this `tr`, so you can just make the necessary amendments to the DOM (and also figure out which comment was clicked on the client-side) by finding the wrapping table row with a class of `comment`.

So, in short, you need some kind of identifier on each comment that allows you to use jQuery to determine which comment was clicked.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of this. My only thought with this method is how do you ensure security? How would you prevent any tampering with the `data-commentid` HTML code on the server end?

Comment: In this scenario, I don't see why you'd need to? I can vote for any comment I want anyway so if I really want to tamper with the markup to vote for a different comment, why stop me? Otherwise, you have two options: (1) Perform a permissions check on the server side to ensure that I'm allowed to vote for this comment; or (2) encrypt/hash all of the comment IDs against distinct key/salts for each comment.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable into the function.

```
onclick='ajaxrequestfunction(this.value)'
```

Then catch the variable in the function:

```
function ajaxrequestfunction(x) {
whatever you want to do = x;
}
```